# useEffect re-render the same result from a supabase query

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, supabase

I'm working with a user's bookmarks list. So, when I tried to render it doing the queries inside useEffect, it renders the result each time.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    async function getBookmarks() {
        await supabase
            .from('bookmarks')
            .select('post_id')
            .match({ user_id: user.id })
            .then(res => {
                res.data.map(async (bk) => {
                    await supabase
                        .from('post')
                        .select('id,description,songlink,created_at,author,profiles:author(username)')
                        .match({ id: bk.post_id })
                        .single()
                        .then(res => setPosts(posts => [...posts, res.data]))
                })
            })
    }   

    getBookmarks()
}, [])
```

I don't want to get the same result twice or more, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can also use Row Level Security to fetch just the results corresponding to the user:

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth#row-level-security

Comment: Remember that `useEffect` (re)runs every single time `render()` runs. Is it supposed to do that? If not, use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Answer (score 1):

it might be helpful to get a better understanding of what you're wanting it to do vs what it's actually doing for people to help answer this better. What I'm seeing here in the code is you asking for data and then asking again. Knowing the data structure of your tables could help, and I'm not sure that you need to be doing multiple fetch calls here.

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select

if your tables are joined, you should be able to just do something like

```
.from('bookmarks').select(`post_id:post_id ( id, description, songlink, created_at )
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use useCallback hook. Didn't try the code but you can get the idea:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

const getBookmarks = useCallback(async ()=>{
      await supabase
            .from('bookmarks')
            .select('post_id')
            .match({ user_id: user.id })
            .then(res => {
                res.data.map(async (bk) => {
                    await supabase
                        .from('post')
                        .select('id,description,songlink,created_at,author,profiles:author(username)')
                        .match({ id: bk.post_id })
                        .single()
                        .then(res => setPosts(posts => [...posts, res.data]))
                })
            })

},[])

useEffect(() => {
    getBookmarks()
}, [])
```